# SSRS Dataset Query - An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am attempting to correlate two databases together with the following query:

```
SELECT     AE.EventTimeStamp, AE.SourceName, AE.Message, AE.Severity, AE.GroupPath
FROM       FTAE_History.dbo.AllEvent AE
    JOIN BatchHistoryEx.dbo.SequenceActiveUnit ActiveUnits
        ON @RecipeName = ActiveUnits.SequenceName
        AND ActiveUnits.ActiveUnit like (CONCAT('%',RIGHT(AE.GroupPath,CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(AE.GroupPath))-1),'%'))
WHERE AE.EventTimeStamp between @StartTime_UTC and @EndTime_UTC
AND LEN(AE.GroupPath) > 13
        AND AE.Active = 1
        AND AE.Severity >= 500
ORDER BY EventTimeStamp
```

When run in SQL Management Studio, I can execute on any @RecipeName or @StartTime_UTC/@EndTime_UTC. When I embed this query in an SSRS dataset, some @RecipeName's or times throw this error:

```
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
 Query execution failed for dataset 'GetUniqueID_BatchIDForAlarms'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
 An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.
```

The error is happening inside the JOIN statement - when I remove that block all possible parameters entered execute even in SSRS. What is causing the difference? How best do I implement an error handling system to allow this query to execute without exceptions?

Comment: How is your report parameter setup (I'm assuming that `@RecipeName` is a report parameter. What datatype, is it multivalue etc? Alternatively, could you not remove the join and add `WHERE ActiveUnits.SequenceName = @RecipeName`. The only other thing, does AE.GroupPath always contain a `.` ?

Comment: Wow. @RecipeName is a Text Report Parameter, and it was configured to allow for Multiple Values. When I specify the value with a DECLARE statement in SSMS while testing, I'm missing that piece of the puzzle. Removing the checkbox to allow for Blank and Multiple Value has fixed the issue. You're the man, Alan.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted out.